# Отобразить/скрыть кнопку в toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-toolbar

Приветствую, не получается динамически выводить кнопку в toolbar. Надо чтобы она появлялась если EditText не пустой

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tootbar);
    Button getCodeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getCodeBtn);
    EditText phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ваш номер телефона");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);


    phoneNumber.setHint("+ Номер телефона");
    phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
    String number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(number)){
        ТУТ ВЫВОДИМ
    } else {
        ТУТ СКРЫВАЕМ
    }
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/getCodeBtn"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24px"
    />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно запомнить `menuItem` во время инициализации меню и управлять его видимостью при помощи подписки на изменение текста:

```
// элемент меню, чьей видимостью будем управлять
private MenuItem _codeMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    // ...

    // добавим подписку с переопределённым методом для управления видимостью
    text.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            super.afterTextChanged(s);

            String number = s.toString();
            _codeMenuItem.setVisible(!TextUtils.isEmpty(number));
        }
    });

    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    // запомним кнопку меню
    _codeMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.getCodeBtn);
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое